# Text getting dislocated when it is used on the second time

Tags: android, andengine

When I am using a loading scene to switch between two scenes in an AndEngine game, the text "Loading..." gets dislocated from its original position when I try to use it on the second time!

How to fix it?

> [image: This is the error in loading scene]

**Code**

```
public void loadGameScene(final Engine mEngine)
{
    setScene(loadingScene);
    loadingScene.logTextPos();
    ResourcesManager.getInstance().unloadMenuTextures();
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            ResourcesManager.getInstance().loadGameResources();
            gameScene = new GameScene();
            setScene(gameScene);
        }
    }));
}

public void loadMenuScene(final Engine mEngine)
{
    setScene(loadingScene);
    loadingScene.logTextPos();
    gameScene.disposeScene();
    ResourcesManager.getInstance().unloadGameTextures();
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            ResourcesManager.getInstance().loadMenuTextures();
            setScene(menuScene);
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: can you share code snippets ?

Comment: here is the code to switch between gameScene and menuScene via loading scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by camera. There is only one camera object at a time in AndEngine. If you move camera in the `gameScene` it stays in its new position in `loadingScene` too. Try reseting the camera position or create another loading scene as a camera scene (like a HUD, just opaque).

Comment: Thank you i was not setting HUD correctly while returning to menuScene.